# Protocol designing subclasses

Tags: python

I had a interview with one of the companies and they asked me this question?

What are the protocols you follow while designing sub-classes. My answer was if the subclasses share all the properties and methods of the parent class and plus it wants to implement its own methods and properties than implement subclass.

Can someone let me know the list of items that needs to be looked into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer was a good start, but they probably were looking for more:

For example:

- Is a subclass the appropriate solution in this case?

  How much of the parent class's functionality will be appropriate for
  the subclass?

  Are you subclassing at the correct level of granularity: is your
  subclass 'final' - an endpoint which will represent the end of an
  inheritance chain, or an intermediate class that will be the parent
  class for other subclasses to follow?

  Do you need only one subclass, or perhaps several that reflect
  different aspects of the parent class's functionality and add their
  own.

  What aspects of the new functionality will be implemented in the
  subclass itself, and how much might be delegated to other classes or
  subsystems.

  Sounds simple, but following an appropriate **NAMING PROTOCOL** for your
  classes and subclasses is also very important: make sure the name of your
  subclass correctly describes its functionality and its
  relationship to the parent class.

Some things to research - the GOF book is a tough read but 'Head First Design Patterns' is more accessible, although sometimes it gets into very elementary details. There may be Python specific design books out there too, but offhand I'm not familiar with them.

Relevant subjects might be:

*) Inheritance

*) Object composition/delegation vs inheritance

*) Abstract classes/Interfaces

Comment: thanks much..Even though I worked on but could not comprehend as you have written

Comment: It's not an easy question to answer - very broad in scope and inheritance has many downsides - caution required.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles are a good place to start.